# which of these two methods of converting this array to integer you would suggest?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, integer

consider the following array of bytes that is intended to be converted into a single unsigned integer:

```
unsigned char arr[3] = {0x23, 0x45, 0x67};
```

each byte represents the equivalent byte in integer, now which one of the following methods would you suggest specially performance-wise:

```
unsigned int val1 = arr[2] << 16 | arr[1] << 8 | arr[0];
//or
unsigned int val2=arr[0];
*((char *)&val2+1)=arr[1];
*((char *)&val2+2)=arr[2];
```

Comment: Compile, disassemble, compare... That will depend on your compiler.

Comment: Supposing that SO suggests one of them, but when you test it with the compiler and platforms you care about, the other one is faster. So what's SO's suggestion worth, compared with your test? ;-)

Comment: How many millions of times per second do you want to perform that operation? What other operations are being processed in the same tight loop? Unless the first answer is quite high and the second quite small, you should better look somewhere else for improving performance.

Comment: @dribeas: the typical case where the first answer is high and the second is small, is "I'm decoding a 24bit RGB image format to 32bit RGBA". Although in that case, or any case of an array of 3-byte data items, this might not be the correct optimization, since there may be an opportunity to read memory more efficiently in word-sized pieces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on your specific processor, *a lot*.

For example, on the PowerPC, the second form -- writing through the character pointers -- runs into a tricky implementation detail called a *load-hit-store*. This is a CPU stall that occurs when you store to a location in memory, then read it back again before the store has completed. The load op cannot complete until the store has finished (most PPCs do not have memory store-forwarding), and the store may take many cycles to make it from the CPU out to the memory cache.

Because of the way the store and arithmetic units are arranged in the pipeline, the CPU will have to flush the pipeline completely until the store completes: this can be a stall of twenty cycles or more during which the CPU has stopped dead. In general, writing to memory and then reading it back immediately is very bad on this platform. So on this case, the sequential bitshifts will be much faster, as they all occur on registers, and will not incur a pipeline stall.

On the Pentium series, the situation may be entirely reversed, because that chipset *does* have store forwarding and a fast stack architecture, and relatively few architectural registers. On the Core Duos and i7s, it may reverse yet again, because their pipelines are very deep.

Remember: *it is not the case that every opcode takes one cycle.* CPUs are not simple, and things like [superscalar pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar) and [data hazards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_%28computer_architecture%29) may cause instructions to take many cycles, or even many instructions to occur per cycle, depending on just how you arrange your code.

All of this just to underscore the point: this sort of optimization is extremely specific to a particular compiler and chipset. So you must compile, test and measure.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer the first method because it is portable. The second isn't due to [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues.

Answer (score 4):

the first is faster, translated in x86 asm. It depends on your architecture anyway. Usually the compilers are able to optimize the first expression very well, and it's more portable too

Answer (score 2):

The performance depends on the compiler and the machine. For example, in my experiment with gcc 4.4.5 on x64 the second was marginally faster, while others report the first as being faster. Therefore I recommend to stick with the first one because it is cleaner (no casts) and safer (no endianness issues).

Comment: @vitaut_if I find second is faster I'd go with that not first.

Comment: @Pooria: You missed my main point that the performance is target and compiler dependent. Have you identified this piece of code as being performance critical part of your project?

Comment: @vitaut_No I didn't that's why I used "If I find second is faster".

Answer (score 1):

I believe bitshift will the fastest solution.  In my mind the CPU can just slide in the values, but by going directly to the address, like your second example, it will have to use many temp storages.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a solution with union :

```
union color { 
    // first representation (member of union) 
    struct s_color { 
        unsigned char a, b, g, r;
    } uc_color;

    // second representation (member of union) 
    unsigned int int_color; 
};

int main()
{
  color a;
  a.int_color = 0x23567899;
  a.uc_color.a;
  a.uc_color.b;
  a.uc_color.g;
  a.uc_color.r;
}
```

Take care that it platform dependent (which endianess)

Comment: In some circumstances, yes. Though if you have an array with three bytes as in the OP rather than `sizeof ( unsigned int )` bytes, then it's random what value happens to be read in for the forth byte ( assuming it doesn't cause an access violation ) if you cast to a union, or else you have to copy the three bytes into the union, and lose some efficiency. You also might need to specify padding on some compilers if you use a struct with separate values rather than a char[3] as the input side of the union.